# Doubt about the computation of the volume of a sphere

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Consider the measure $d\Omega_{n+1}$ as a invariant measure induced by the Lebesgue measure on the unit sphere $\mathbb{S}\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. I want to calculate $d\Omega_{n+1}(\mathbb{S})$. I know that I could get there using of polar coordinates and calculating the integral $\int e^{-a\lVert x\rVert^2} dx$. The book I'm reading takes a different approach, and I don't understand it.

The books follows this argument: if $\omega$ is a point of the sphere, and $\{e_j\}$ is a orthonormal base for $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, i can write it as $\omega = te_{n+1} + \sqrt{1-t^2}\omega^\prime, t\in [-1,1]$ where $\omega^\prime$ is an element of the sphere $\mathbb{S}^\prime$ on  the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ generated by the first n vectors in the base.

The autor proceeds to afirm that if we represent $\omega$ as $t$ and $\omega^\prime$ we have: $$d\Omega_{n+1}(\omega) = (1-t^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}} \, dt \, (1-t^2)^\frac{n-1}{2} \, d\Omega_{n}(\omega^\prime)=(1-t^2)^\frac{n-2}{2} \, dt \, d\Omega_{n}(\omega^\prime)$$

It looks very similar to how we change variables in calculus, but I don't remember seeing this in measure theory, neither could I find something similar by looking at the texts. The rest of the argument is easy to follow. Can someone help me understand whats happening here?

Comment: What book is this?

Comment: @Reveillark Analytic Functionals on the Sphere by Mitsuo Morimoto